# R Shiny App Error: Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am new to R Shiny and attempting to alter code to create a predictive model on if we should ski based upon the weather. The app looks great until I click submit, and then I get the errors below.

```
Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3
  128: stop
  127: data.frame
  126: <reactive:datasetInput> [C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/Data-Analysis-Portfolio/R Shiny Apps/Skiing_weather/Skiing_weather_app.R#87]
  110: datasetInput
   97: renderTable [C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/Data-Analysis-Portfolio/R Shiny Apps/Skiing_weather/Skiing_weather_app.R#125]
   96: func
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$tabledata
    1: runApp
```

Here is my code:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                
                # Page header
                headerPanel('Do We Ski Today?'),
                
                # Input values
                sidebarPanel(
                  HTML("<h3>Input parameters</h3>"),
                  
                  selectInput("outlook", label = "Outlook:", 
                              choices = list("sunny", "overcast","rainy", "snow"), 
                              selected = "Sunny"),
                  sliderInput("temperature", label = "Temperature:",
                              min = 10, max = 37,
                              value = 15),
                  sliderInput("humidity", label = "Humidity:",
                              min = 30, max = 45,
                              value = 40),
                  selectInput("Visability", label = "Visability:", 
                              choices = list("Good", "Poor"), 
                              selected = "Good"),
                  
                  actionButton("submitbutton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                  tags$label(h3('Status/Output')), # Status/Output Text Box
                  verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
                  tableOutput('tabledata') # Prediction results table
                  
                )
)

####################################
# Server                           #
####################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Input Data
  datasetInput <- reactive({  
    
    # outlook,temperature,windy,humidity,visability,ski
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = c("outlook",
               "temperature",
               "humidity",
               "visability"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$outlook,
                             input$temperature,
                             input$humidity,
                             input$visability)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    ski <- "ski"
    df <- rbind(df, ski)
    input <- transpose(df)
    write.table(input,"input.csv", sep=",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    
    test <-  read.csv(file='input.csv')
    
    test$outlook <- factor(test$outlook, levels = c("overcast", "rainy", "sunny", "snow"))
    test$ski <- factor(test$ski, levels = c("yes", "no"))

    Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(model,test), round(predict(model,test,type="prob"), 4))
    print(Output)
    
  })
  
  # Status/Output Text Box
  output$contents <- renderPrint({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate("Calculation complete.") 
    } else {
      return("Server is ready for calculation.")
    }
  })
  
  # Prediction results table
  output$tabledata <- renderTable({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate(datasetInput()) 
    } 
  })
  
}
```

I have made the variables outlook and ski factors. When I open the data "ui" I see a "NULL" value under [[2]] which I think might be making the error, but I don't know for sure. When I run `print(Output)' I get an output table with the prediction, but it doesn't display on the app.

```
>     test <-  read.csv(file='input.csv')
>     test$outlook <- factor(test$outlook, levels = c("overcast", "rainy", "sunny", "snow"))
>     test$ski <- factor(test$ski, levels = c("yes", "no"))
>     Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(model,test), round(predict(model,test,type="prob"), 4))
>     print(Output)
  Prediction    no   yes
1        yes 0.062 0.938
```

I have scoured the web with not much luck. Hoping someone where can help out a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use `input$Visability` (with capital V) since it's how you named the `selectInput`.

Comment: OMG. Capital letters. THANK YOU. IT WORKED!